# Can I implement a record as a class in programming languages that uses it?

Tags: class, records, implements

My instructor for "Programing Languages Design & implementation" course asked us to do a homework, and this homework asks that: "can you implement a record as a class ?"

Comment: What programming language are you talking about? Java don't have struct by the way.

Comment: The instructor didn't specify. I guess you can answer for any Programming language, let's say: c++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can. If you are referring a record just like a row of record from the database:

Student Record in **database**:

```
Student Name: Alice
Student ID: S001
Gender: F
```

Student in **Struct** (Implemented in C)

```
struct Student
{
    char name[MAX];
    char id[MAX];
    char gender;
};
struct Student stud1 = {"Alice", "S001", 'F'};
```

Student in **Class** (C has no class, implemented in Java)

```
class Student
{
    String name;
    String id;
    char gender;

    public Student (String name, String id, char gender)
    {        
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.gender = gendeer;
    }
}
Student stud1 = new Student1("Alice", "S001", 'F');
```

If the context of C++, the same thing applies. In C++, you can have struct and classes. Struct cannot have method (functions) in them, but classes can have. Since classes can similarly "group" data together, and on top of that, provide methods. You can definitely implement a struct as a class.